# Troca rápida e contínua da cor de background de um Panel

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou tentando fazer com que uma panel fique trocando constantemente de cor com o seguinte código

```
while (true)
{
   panelColor.BackColor = Color.Blue;
   Thread.Sleep(500);
   panelColor.BackColor = Color.Red;
   Thread.Sleep(500);
}
```

O problema é que a aplicação trava todoa vez que chega nessa parte, alguem pode me dizer o por quê?

Comment: Isso é um loop infinito, a execução nunca sairá dele.

Comment: teoricamente não deveria ficar trocando as cores com o intervalo de 500 milisegundos nesse loop?

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, era isso mesmo, esqueci do refresh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A aplicação trava porque está a executar um *loop* infinito.

Você também não vê o background a mudar de cor pela mesma razão, como a UIThread está bloqueada a executar esse código, o framework do windows não tem oportunidade de redesenhar os controles.

Altere o código da seguinte forma:

```
while (true)
{
   panelColor.BackColor = Color.Blue;
   panelColor.Refresh();
   Thread.Sleep(500);

   panelColor.BackColor = Color.Red;
   panelColor.Refresh();
   Thread.Sleep(500);
}
```

O método [refresh()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh(v=vs.110).aspx) faz o controle auto redesenhar-se.